# CIFS auto mounted shares on shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, cifs

Running Ubuntu I've recently encountered an issue with shutting down the computer - it simply hangs whenever I shutdown, whether from the GUI or command line with `sudo shutdown -hP now`

```
~$ uname -a
Linux mythbuntu 3.0.0-17-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a handful of cifs entries in my /etc/fstab which are set to auto so that they mount on boot.

```
~$ cat /etc/fstab | grep cifs
//remoteserver/stuff    /mnt/remoteserver/stuff cifs ro,username=myuser,password=mypass,nobootwait,auto 0 0
//remoteserver/public   /mnt/remoteserver/public cifs rw,username=myuser,user,suid,noatime,nobootwait,auto 0 0
```

I added nobootwait but it seems to make no difference (advice on a different forum)

When I change **auto** for **noauto** the system doesn't hang, but I want these mounts to be attempted on startup.

I've hunted the internet for information on fixes, and there are plenty of suggestions but no concrete answers.  The messages I see on shutdown seem to suggest that unattended-upgrades service is trying to use mountall after the network service has already come down, and failing to mount the network shares.  The last bit of output mentions starting then almost immediately stopping  an apache2 webserver for some reason. I've also seen this error on shutdown `umount //proc/fs/nfsd: device is busy` There are no nfs mounts in my fstab.

Am I trying to use CIFS incorrectly? Is there a better way to mount shares on the network that doesn't suffer from this problem? (Its for a media centre type config, so everything should be automatic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [uSlackr](https://superuser.com/users/11051/uslackr)'s answer, I modified the `mount_shares_locally` script (below)

- I created this file as `/etc/init.d/mount_shares_locally`
- Then `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mount_shares_locally` to make it executable
- I created a directory `sudo mkdir /var/lock/subsys/`
- I added `noauto` to each of my cifs shares options, to prevent them being automatically mounted during a `mountall`
- Made sure that `sudo service mount_shares_locally restart` gave no errors
- And finally added it to the startup/shutdown  runlevels with `sudo update-rc.d mount_shares_locally defaults`

---

```
#!/bin/sh
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mount_shares_locally
# Required-Start:    $network $local_fs $remote_fs smb mysqld
# Required-Stop:     $network $local_fs $remote_fs smb
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: mount Samba shares locally
### END INIT INFO

if [ -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]; then  # "/lib/lsb/init-functions" on Ubuntu
    . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
fi

start () {  
    echo -n "Mounting Samba shares locally:\n"

    cat /etc/fstab | grep 'cifs.*\(password\|credentials\)' | while read -r remoteServer localMount type options;
    do
        echo Mounting $remoteServer to $localMount
        mount $localMount
    done

    touch /var/lock/subsys/mount_shares_locally
    echo
    return 0
}

stop () {
    echo -n "Unmounting locally mounted Samba shares:\n"

    cat /etc/fstab | grep 'cifs.*\(password\|credentials\)' | while read -r remoteServer localMount type options;
    do
        echo Unmounting $localMount
        umount $localMount
    done

    rm -f /var/lock/subsys/mount_shares_locally

    echo
    return 0
}

restart () {
    stop
    start
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        restart
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit $?
```

I also had to add another script to the upstart model, so that mount_shares_locally gets called at the right time during startup (after the network is up):

`/etc/init/mount_shares_locally.conf`

```
# mount_shares_locally - Mount any cifs shares in /etc/fstab when network comes online
#

description "Mount CIFS shares"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on (runlevel [!12345] or net-device-down IFACE=eth0)

respawn
console none

pre-start script
    mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/mount_shares_locally
    exec /etc/init.d/mount_shares_locally start
end script

post-stop script
    mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/mount_shares_locally
    exec /etc/init.d/mount_shares_locally stop
end script
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a "service" that unmaps these during shutdown. I use a script on my Fedora/Amahi server to do this.  It will need to be tweaked for Ubuntu, but the theory works.

More here: http://wiki.amahi.org/index.php/Mount_Shares_Locally